# menu item is enabled, but still grayed out

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder, nsmenuitem

I have a menu with several items created in interface builder. It looks fine there and 'enabled' is checked. But when I run the application, all menu items are grayed out.

I've checked `isEnabled`, it returns true.

Also, menu items created programmatically (with `initWithTitle` and without interface builder) work just fine.

Am I missing something here? I'm really quite new to OS X development.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case somebody might google this out and benefit, 'Action' method was declared without `:(id)sender` parameter:

```
-(IBAction) quit;
```

Strangely, `setAction` method in `NSMenuItem` ate it and didn't complain. Oh well.

Comment: If you passed `quit` as the action selector, I would have expected that to work. If you passed `quit:`, that's why: `quit:` is a different method from the `quit` (no `:`) method you implemented. `quit`, `quit:`, `quit::`, and `quit:inAHuff:` are all different selectors.

Answer (score 31):

Remember to set your menu item's target and ensure that said target implements the menu item's action method.

```
menuItem.target = self;
```

> - If the menu item’s target is set, then NSMenu first checks to see if that object implements the item’s action method. If it does not, then **the item is disabled**. If the target does implement the item’s action method, NSMenu first checks to see if that object implements validateMenuItem: or validateUserInterfaceItem: method. If it does not, then the menu item is enabled. If it does, then the enabled status of the menu item is determined by the return value of the method.
> - If the menu item’s target is not set and the NSMenu object is not a contextual menu, then NSMenu uses the responder chain to determine the target. If there is no object in the responder chain that implements the item’s action, **the item is disabled**.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html

Comment: The target is the first responder (set in IB by control dragging from menu item to first responder proxy object). The action is in the view controller which nowadays is suppose to be in the responder chain. Still greyed out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the plague of using `NSMenu`...

Check out [`<NSMenuValidation>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSMenuValidation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Usually the implementation will be as simple as:

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)menuItem {
  return [menuItem isEnabled];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! With some fiddling, I've tracked down the root cause myself, but +1 for the useful information.

Comment: I don't think this will satisfy the menu item if the target does not respond to the action.